# Template parse errors: is not a known element

Tags: angular

I have a midi component defined as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'midi-midi-lib',
  templateUrl: './midi-lib.component.html'
})

export class MidiLibComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

I also have a home component defined as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

whose template contains the markup:

```
<midi-midi-lib></midi-midi-lib>
```

The `midilib` component is included in its own module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MidiLibComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [
    MidiLibComponent,
  ]
})
export class MidiLibModule { }
```

with the application module containing it:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MidiLibModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Note that the above code is trimmed from many other components and modules.

The source tree is like:

```
src
├── app
├── lib
```

with the `Midi` component being under the `lib` directory.

If I then call the route defined as:

```
{
  path: 'home',
  loadChildren: './views/home/home.module#HomeModule',
  data: {
    preload: true,
    delay: false
  }
},
```

with the https://dev.thalasoft.com:4200/home url then the page shows the error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:\n'midi-midi-lib' is not a known element
```

If I type in a terminal the `ng build --prod` command then I get the same error:

```
ERROR in : 'midi-midi-lib' is not a known element:
1. If 'midi-midi-lib' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'midi-midi-lib' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>
      [ERROR ->]<midi-midi-lib></midi-midi-lib>
    </p>
  </mat-card-content>
")
```

Whereas if I call the route defined as:

```
{
  path: 'midi',
  component: MidiLibComponent
},
```

in the `app-routing.module` file with the `https://dev.thalasoft.com:4200/midi` url then the component is found and its content is displayed just fine.

I'm under `Angular 8.1.3`

Comment: Why is the `lib` module outside the `app` directory? Not quite sure about this but I don't think Angular will compile it out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are lazy loading `HomeComponent`, `MidiLibModule` should be imported in `HomeModule` instead of `AppModule`. Also in Angular 8 it is recommended to use dynamic import in your routing module like:

```
{
  path: 'home',
  loadChildren: () => import('./views/home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule),
  data: {
    preload: true,
    delay: false
  }
},
```

Comment: I still get the message `Component MidiLibComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.` even if I don't use the new ng8 dynamic import.

Comment: I think it's because iny I also had another route using the `MidiLibComponent` component like `{
        path: 'music',
        component: MidiLibComponent
      }` When removing it the error is gone.

Comment: If you're using MidiLibComponent outside HomeModule in a different module you need to import MidiLibModule into that module as well.